# How to make div with an image and text in exact center in Ionic?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have a login screen. I want to make it vertically and horizontally in the center. My login screen has a title with an image. It also should be in the center with respect to the text box.

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="loginscreen">
        <div class="col-80 col-offset-10">
            <div class="row widthclass">
                <div>
                    <img src="img/clock.png" alt="clock" class="clockwidth"></img>
                </div>
                <div class="timesheettext2">
                    <h1 class="timesheettext">
                        <b>Timesheet Tracking</b>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="formpadding col-80  col-offset-10">
                <form novalidate name="loginForm" ng-submit="doLogin(loginForm)">
                    <label class="item item-input labelusername">
                        <i class="icon  placeholder-icon"><img src="img/user.png" alt="" style="width:20px;height:20px;"/></i>
                        <input name="UserName" type="text" ng-model="User.UserName" placeholder="Username or Email" required>
                    </label>
                    <p ng-show="loginForm.UserName.$error.required && loginSubmitted" class="usernameerror">
                        Please provide username
                    </p>
                    <label class="item item-input labelpassword">
                        <i class="icon  placeholder-icon"><img src="img/password.png" alt="" style="width:20px;height:20px;"/></i>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="User.Password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </label>
                    <p ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.required && loginSubmitted" class="usernameerror">
                        Provide password
                    </p>
                    <p ng-show="myflag">
                      Wrong credentials
                    </p>

                    <button class="button button-block button-lightgreen" type="submit">
                      <p class="login">
                        <b>Submit</b>
                      </p>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I am not providing my CSS file; it's a little complex. If you want, you can change my classes.

Answer (score 2):

Just give the following CSS will make your screen vertically and horizontally center.

```
.loginscreen {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ngxb75w/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
.loginscreen {
    text-align: center
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11559421)

Comment: @user1697575: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​No, it is an answer. Code-only answers maybe aren't helpful, but they're still answers.